# Resizing PApplet in a JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, processing

I've been trying to stick a PApplet in a JFrame and have it resize when the user changes the size of the JFrame, but the documentation, when it exists, is unclear. [Here](http://processing.org/discourse/yabb2/YaBB.pl?num=1199275961) I am told to use

```
void setup() {
  frame.setResizable(true);
}

void resize(int w, int h) {
  super.resize(w,h);
  frame.setSize(w,h);
}
```

but when I try that it seems frame is null, and I'm not clear on how to make sure that resize get's called, anyway.

Has anyone gotten this to work?

EDIT: simplified code.

Here is some of my code, based on http://wiki.processing.org/w/Swing_JSliders:

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
    public MyPanel()
    {
        //have tried both BoxLayout and BorderLayout
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        //if, instead of a PApplet I use a JPanel, this resizes fine
        // it's only when using a PApplet that it won't resize
        //add our processing window
        PApplet pa = new PApplet();
        pa.init();
        add(pa);
    }

    // create external JFrame
    private static void createGui()
    {
        // create new JFrame
        JFrame jf = new JFrame("test");

        // this allows program to exit
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
        // You add things to the contentPane in a JFrame
        jf.getContentPane().add(new MyPane());

        // keep window from being resized
        //jf.setResizable(false);

        // size frame
        jf.pack();

        // make frame visible
        jf.setVisible(true);
    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // threadsafe way to create a Swing GUI
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    createGui();
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

thanks, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: From my reading, PApplet is an AWT based component that is derived from Applet. Are you sure that you want to place it in a Swing application/JPanel? Also, what if your JPanel uses a BorderLayout and adds the PApplet BorderLayout.CENTER (and the other component in another BorderLayout location)?

Comment: I'm putting it in a JPanel because I want to pair it with a non-processing GUI and http://wiki.processing.org/w/Swing_JSliders
offered a way of doing that. As for using BorderLayout, it holds the PApplet just fine, but I still don't know how to resize it, it doesn't do it automatically.

Comment: @Dogmatixed: *"As for using BorderLayout, it holds the PApplet just fine, ..resize.., it doesn't do it automatically"*  It should if you are adding it to the CENTER constraint (an no other layouts are forcing the container with `BorderLayout` to be it's smallest size).  For better help sooner, try and make an [SSCCE](http://pscode.org/sscce.html) with a plain colored panel in place of the `PApplet`.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson: It works fine with a colored JPanel, but not with a PApplet.

Comment: In that case I think HFOE is right about mixing light/heavyweight.  Java 7 is supposed to support it without problems.  Is 7 an option?

Comment: It could be, would that just magically fix this? Is there really NO way to do this in Java 6? What if it were all done in AWT, wrapped in a Frame, instead?

Comment: Well, I've just tried wrapping it in a Frame, and I experience the same problem. I don't think it's Swing/AWT that's the issue, I think I'm just looking for a way to get a Container to communicate its size changes to a PApplet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple, actually. It seems that unless draw is being used the PApplet won't get resized. It's as simple as turning

```
PApplet pa = new PApplet();
```

into

```
PApplet pa = new PApplet()
{
public void draw(){};
};
```

or replacing it with a properly extended PApplet.

I just didn't make my personal proof-of-concept detailed enough.